# Wheel spinner control for windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there a good wheelspinner control for the windows phone 7?  I'd like something like the date or time picker, but I want to use it for data sources other than dates and times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LoopingSelector in [Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888). Also these [tutorials](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/21-WP7-Toolkit-in-Depth-articles-covering-all-controls) will be useful for you